# Middling text horizontally and vertically in a div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created a `div` in HTML:

```
  .Div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  }
  ...
    <div class="Div">
    Just testing my Div.
    </div>
  ...
```

Output:
[image]

I want the text to be in the middle of this rectangular, vertically and horizontally. How should I make it happen?

To be mentioned, I didn't use this `div` inside the main body, it's used inside another `div`; But in that i also have `text-align: center;`. I don't know if it's important; But i can provide more details about this code if needed.

P.S: I'm very new to css and html. Please accept my apologies if this code doesn't meet some standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. **Since you, yourself tried to use [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) in the first place, so `vertical-align` will only work with `display: table-cell;`**. In order to achieve it, **you should set your `div`, `display` to `table-cell` and then you should also define a specific `width` for your `div`** (I just went with [`100vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) to fill the available viewport).

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
.Div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div">
  Just testing my Div.
</div>
```

But **if you want some generic approach for this you should use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** instead. In order to use `flexbox`, you should define three specific properties to meet your requirement.

1. **`display: flex;`**. This will **indicate your `div` as flex items and then their children should follow flex rules.**
2. **`align-items: center;`**. This will indicate all of your items should **align in the middle of your `div` horizontally.**
3. **`justify-content: center;`**. This will indicate all of your items should **align in the middle of your `div` vertically.**

```css
.Div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div">
  Just testing my Div.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `display: flex;`, `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center` in your class `Div`

You may go http://howtocenterincss.com/, to auto-generate the code that centre text, image or div.

```css
.Div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  /* text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; */
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div">
  Just testing my Div.
</div>
```